# Starting an activity when the user leaves the current activity using the home button in Android app development

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-homebutton

Android app development: Trying to launch another activity when the home button is clicked 3 times in the main activity, but the code is not working. Can someone help with my code?

```
    HomeWatcher mHomeWatcher = new HomeWatcher(this);
    mHomeWatcher.setOnHomePressedListener(new OnHomePressedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHomePressed() {
            T++; // to track the clicks
            if (T==3){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Home button pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
                startActivity( new Intent (getBaseContext(),Main2Activity.class));}

            // do something here...
        }
        
    });
    mHomeWatcher.startWatch();
     }

@Override
public void onStop() {


        //Toast.makeText(this, "onstop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if ( T==3 ){
        startActivity( new Intent (getBaseContext(),Main2Activity.class));}
    super.onStop();

}
```

Comment: Check if `onHomePressed()` is invoked. If not, then add a debug point in `HomeWatcher` and check it that's working. Btw, I guess you are just experimenting with this idea. Please do not push this idea in your production app. It's bad design.

Comment: Don't you think you have an extra closing curly bracket `}` at the end of Toast which in this case possible reason for the error?